# Google Apps Script - return row with oldest date from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that looks like the following:

| Team | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 8/17/2023 9:21:13 |
| B | 8/18/2023 9:22:13 |
| C | 8/19/2023 9:23:13 |
| D | 8/20/2023 9:24:13 |
| E | 8/21/2023 9:25:13 |

Using AppScript, I'd like to return the find the row with the earliest date/time and return the value in Column A "Team". Furthermore I'd like to overwrite the value of Column B "Timestamp" with todays date/time.

While I use google sheets a lot, I am a novice with scripting. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, we'd have to first extract the contents of the sheet to an array, then sort the said array in order to identify the team with the earliest date/time. Based on your question, I assume that you would also like to change the date/time of the team with the earliest date to today's date though let us know and update the question if that is not the case.

You can try the following:

```
function sheetSort(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Change this to the name of the sheet you're pulling the data from.
  var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  /*getRange()will highlight the cells from A1 to the last row and column that contains data.
  You can then use getValues() to store it as an array.*/
  var sorted = values.toSorted((a, b) => a[1]-b[1]);
  var oldDatePos = values.indexOf(sorted[1])+1;
  
  sheet.getRange(oldDatePos,2).setValue(new Date()); 
  return sorted[1][0];
}
```

Note that the code above assumes that the data is stored in `A:B`.

## References

- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding#getrange)
- [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Hi user1180997, was the answer provided able to fix your issue? 

Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you